# Calling a VB Script from a Powershell script produces unexpected runtime errors when sending automated emails

Tags: powershell, outlook, vbscript

I have the following VB Script:

```
Set MSOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailMsg = MSOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With MailMsg            
        .To = "xyz@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "my subject"
        .HTMLBody = "my text"
        .Display
        SendKeys "{TAB}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}", True
        .Send
End With

Set MSOutlook = Nothing
Set MailMsg = Nothing
```

This script runs fine when executed within a VB compiler, such as `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications`.

The `SendKeys` is required because of this damn `Titus` classification system we have in place at work to classify everything, such as emails and documents.

The email sends fine and it is classified correctly.

Now I am trying to call this script from the following Powershell script:

`& cscript 'C:\Documents\sendEmail.vbs' //nologo`

But the following error is received either in the Powershell ISE or when calling the vb script directly from a PowerShell console:

`cscript.exe : C:\Documents\sendEmail.vbs Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'SendKeys'`

Anyone know much about this and why the SendKeys function apparently cannot be used this way?

To pre-empt comments, yes, I would really like to move this vb functionality into the PowerShell script but the TITUS plugin is causing all sorts of headaches around that right now.

Thanks

Comment: We used to use Titus until we swapped to email classification, then dset. Why not just Powershell to do it all for you instead of calling on a VBScript?

Comment: I agree. You're asking for trouble by chaining together so many scripts.... with a sendkey on the end. I suggest you write the entire thing in Powershell. OR take Powershell out of it and just use `cscript.exe`

Comment: That's the plan, I just wanted to get something working "in practice" first -  the idea being to port all this legacy vb stuff to PS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA, the `SendKeys` command is a member of the global `Interaction` module and, thus, always in scope.

In VBScript, you need to use the `SendKeys` method of the `WScript.Shell` object instead:

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys "{TAB}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}", True
```